# Conditional adding of values in R with two dataframes

Tags: r, match, dplyr

I have two dataframes (df1, df2).

```
df1 <- data.frame(term = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"))

df2 <- data.frame(term = c("C", "F", "G"), freq = c(7, 3, 5))
```

In df1, I want to add a column ("freq") based on the values of "freq" in df2. So if the term in df1 and the term in df2 match, the count ("freq") of this term should be added to df1. Else it should be "0" (zero).

How can I do it, so that the processing time is as small as possible? Is there a way how to do it with dplyr? I cannot figure it out!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need a faster option, a `data.table` join can be used along with assigning (`:=`) the NA values to 0 in place.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[df1, on = "term"][is.na(freq), freq := 0][]
```

Or to avoid copies, as @Arun mentioned, create a 'freq' column in 'df1' and then join `on` 'term' replace the 'freq' with the corresponding 'i.freq' values.

```
setDT(df1)[, freq := 0][df2, freq := i.freq, on = "term"]
```

Or use `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = 'term') %>%
       mutate(freq = replace(freq, is.na(freq), 0)
```

Comment: I'd do: `setDT(df1)[, freq := 0][df2, freq := i.freq, on = "term"]` which avoids unnecessary copies.